# Trig Sub for $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}$

Tags: calculus

If you integrate $\displaystyle \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}$ using $x= 3 \tan \theta$, you obtain $\ln\left| \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+9}}{3} + \dfrac{x}{3} \right|+C$ whereas if you use the substitution $x=3 \cot \theta$, you obtain $-\ln\left| \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+9}}{3} + \dfrac{x}{3} \right|+C$. However, the function is not periodic so there is no linear shift for $C$ which will make the answers agree. I am certain no mistake was made in the integration (insofar as I can see), how is it that these 'agree'?

Comment: @HarryAlli: The first answer is perfectly correct. And it's perfectly correct without those $3$'s in the denominators too, thanks to properties of logarithms -- the difference would be incorporated by changing the arbitrary constant $C$.

Comment: It's weird though to think about a change of variable $x=3\tan(\theta)$ or $x=3\cot(\theta)$ when $\frac 1{\sqrt{1+u^2}}$ scream for a change in $\sinh(t)$...

Comment: @zwim: Mathematically speaking -- yes, I absolutely agree with you. But school and college Calculus courses often don't mention hyperbolic functions at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your work, it's hard to determine where exactly your solution went wrong, but somewhere it did go wrong. The first answer is perfectly correct. The second answer isn't, although it's quite close. Using this substitution, the correct answer would be
$$-\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2+9}}{3}\color{red}{-}\frac{x}{3}\right|+C=\color{red}{+}\ln\left| \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+9}}{3} + \dfrac{x}{3} \right|+C,$$
because of the antiderivative formula
$$\int\csc x\,dx=\ln\left|\csc x-\cot x\right|+C=-\ln\left|\csc x+\cot x\right|+C.$$

Comment: When you showed the alternate formula, I caught the very obvious problem of dropping an extra negative. But using the other formula does alleviate many issues. Many thanks.